# Is there a way to create Chord Diagram using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram, chord-diagram

I am trying to change the sankey diagram to the chord diagram by using highcharts, However there is no chord diagram available in the highcharts.

Any help on the way to implement it is appreciated.
[image: Chord Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series type will be available in the next Highcharts release. It will be called `dependency-wheel`. Check the Highcharts Roadmap for 7.1: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/roadmap/

Comment: Thanks @WojciechChmiel, I hope the Highcharts Release it soon